# DSolve Solutions are sometimes not as simple as they could be

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, complex

Why doesn't `DSolve` output a solution in a nice format?

```
DSolve[y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> (-3 - I) - x + 1/(-(I/2) + E^(2 I x) C[1])}}
> ```

Ugh!

Maple gives  the correct answer of $y(x) = \tan(x - C) - x - 3$ with no hassle or imaginary terms.

Comment: That's what `Simplify[]`/`FullSimplify[]` is intended for.

Comment: The algorithms used in Mathematica generally operate in the complex plane and the results provided are the ones that come naturally from those algorithms. `C[1] ` is an arbitrary complex constant. Arbitrarily, let `C[1] == -1/2  I Exp[-2 I k]`

Comment: @J.M. but neither will actually simplify this particular solution.

Answer (score 6):

First, let `dsol` denote the *Mathematica* solution:

```
dsol = First@DSolve[y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2, y, x];
y[x] /. dsol
(* (-3 - I) - x + 1/(-(I/2) + E^(2 I x) C[1])  *)
```

Note that `y[x] -> (-3 + I) - x` is an "obvious" solution, if you happen to go looking for one with a constant derivative `y'[x]`, and it is not contained in the form returned by Maple, except as the limit at $-i\,\infty$:

```
Limit[Tan[x - C[2]] - x - 3, C[2] -> -I * Infinity]
(*  (-3 + I) - x  *)
```

In the *Mathematica* solution above, it corresponds to `C[1] -> 0`.  Quite simple.  OTOH, I get the impression that some folks don't care for complex solutions, even when they're simple. :)

Another obvious solution, `y[x] -> (-3 - I) - x` can only be obtained from both the Maple and *Mathematica* solutions as a limit:

```
Limit[(-3 - I) - x + 1/(-(I/2) + E^(2 I x) C[1]), C[1] -> Infinity]
Limit[Tan[x - C[2]] - x - 3, C[2] -> I * Infinity]
(*  both: (-3 - I) - x  *)
```

However, the simpler nature of the *Mathematica* solution allows the projectivization of the constant `C[1] -> C[1]/C[2]`.  Then limits are not needed, but two constants have to be injected to get a particular solution.

```
projsol = y[x] /. dsol /. C[1] -> C[1]/C[2] // Together // Apart
(*  (-3 - I) - x + (2 C[2])/(2 E^(2 I x) C[1] - I C[2])  *)

projsol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1}
projsol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}
(*
  (-3 + I) - x
  (-3 - I) - x
*)
```

This is not so easy to do in the Maple solution, because it is trapped inside `Tan[]`.  You get divide-by-zero errors if you try the straightforward method.

---

Interestingly, if we precondition the problem with a simple and obvious substitution, we get the Maple answer.  So I guess it isn't like *Mathematica* "thinks" the above method is better.

```
toPureFunction[sol_, y_] := sol /. HoldPattern[y[x_] -> body_] :> y -> Function[{x}, body];

sub = toPureFunction[First@Solve[u[x] == x + y[x] + 3, y[x]], y];
y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2 /. sub
usol = DSolve[y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2 /. sub, u, x]
y[x] -> (y[x] /. sub) /. usol
(*
  -1 + u'[x] == u[x]^2                    - transformed ODE
  {{u -> Function[{x}, Tan[x + C[1]]]}}   - solution of transformed ODE
  {y[x] -> -3 - x + Tan[x + C[1]]}        - back-sub.; sol. of orig. ODE
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can verify the solution is valid as follows

```
ode = y'[x] == (x + y[x] + 3)^2;
sol = DSolve[ode, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 ode/.sol//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As to why different CAS give different looking answer, is hard to answer as it depends on many things and we users have no access to the `DSolve` source code to answer exactly why.

Comment: I think the Wolf has to work on DSolve a little more.  Folks will laugh and point at me if I submitted a solution bristling with "i" terms like that.   Especially compared to the neat clean solution that Maple produces immediately with no need to massage the result.